# Using JOTM transaction manager Doesn't works on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, transactions, jotm

Facing a strange problem here, below is the configuration i am using:
1. Apache Tomcat 6.0.26
2. mySql
3. Spring framework+ Hibernate

We have used JOTM for transaction management

```
<bean id="jotm"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean" />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    < property name="userTransaction" ref="jotm" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that i have one service which creates and entity on my local DB and then calls a web service on failiure of which the created entity in local DB should be rolled back. On failure of the web service call i am throwing RunTimeException which should ideally rollback the transaction as per mentioned in the spring configuration file. However this is not happening. Instead of JOTM if i am using Hibernate transaction manager it is rolling back the transaction. Can someone please throw some light on if i am  missing out on anything while implementing through JOTM.

Appreciate the help in advance,

Vaibhav